# Problem in JPA-Mapping

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a situation where my DB tables are like below, I am wondering how to have JPA mappings for this kind of 
tables , espacially for the auction_param_values which do not have primary key ID

**Table Name** :  ***auction*** with primary key as auction_id

**Table Name** : ***auction_param*** with primary key as auction_param_id

Table  `AUCTIO_PARAM`  is used stores the details of parameters such as `Start_Date`,`End_Date` etc.

```
auction_param_id | auction_param_desc 

1                | start date
2                | end_date
```

**Table Name** : **auction_param_values**

It stores the actual values of that parameters related to `Auction`.

Table looks like:-

```
auction_id | auction_param_id | auction_param value | 

   1       |      2           |      2011-01-15     |
```

How will the entity class look for the `auction_param_values` ? is there any pointer on how we can design 
the schema to support JPA (we are using Eclipselink as a provider).

If require I can provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont know if I understood correctly but this might be what you need:

```
@Entity
public class Auction {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pk.auction")
    @MapKey(name="pk.auctionParam")
    private Map<AuctionParam, AuctionParamValue> values;

}

@Entity
public class AuctionParam {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String description;

}

@Entity
public class AuctionParamValue {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AuctionParamValuePK pk;

    private String value;

}

@Embeddable
public class AuctionParamValuePK {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="auction_id")
    private Auction auction;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="auctionparam_id")
    private AuctionParam auctionParam;

}
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply.I  implemented the way you have suggested however I found it is showing an error.And i tried to resolve it but I m unable to figure it out.Error-Details:-Exception Description: Entity [class com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValue] uses [class com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValuePK] as embedded id class whose access-type has been determined as [FIELD]. But [class com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValuePK] does not define any [FIELD]. It is likely that you have not provided sufficient metadata in your id class [class com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValuePK].